# Unable to click on dropdown button in web view of iOS 11 in Appium

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to automate a hybrid app using Appium in iPhone 6 real device.
I am able to locate the dropdown element with path and Appium shows it has clicked on the element also. But it is not actually clicked as the dropdown is not opening.

Please find below attached screenshot of the scenario

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The element is a Select and not just a standard WebElement, so you must treat it as such.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("RelationOption")));
```

Then you directly access which option you wish by visible text, value, or index.

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Mother");
```

Comment: I tried your code. But the dropdown is still not getting opened while Appium is showing as clicked and the test case as passed (Manually I am able to open the dropdown by touching it)

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in Appium and Selenium both, when you use .selectByxxx it doesn't actually drop-down the list, it just selects the value, index, or text you specified.  Does your code not select the value you want showing in the textbox area of the dropdown after running the script?  Are you getting error messages?

Comment: By the way, I'm on my way to the hospital (nothing life-threatening) but I'm likely going to be tied-up all day so I may not be able to respond to your questions for a while, at least the rest of today.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Hileman, I am able to click on the required options present inside the dropdown. But situation here is, the dropdown is getting opened, as the option is present in the html page, it is directly finding the element and clicking it without even opening the dropdown

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the standard behavior.  The idea of the tests is to confirm that the web page or app (in this case) behaves correctly.  There really should be no need for a drop-down control to actually drop down its list to test that it accepts the value and continues with the script.  If anything, that kind of animation would only slow-down the performance speed of the test.  As long as it's selecting the correct option, why would there be a problem?